# Why is package/code signing considered more secure, and how does it work?

Tags: linux, ssh, security, gnupg, digital-signature

Kind of a noob question, but I've been reading about signing and how it makes linux distros more secure. Docker recently added image signing, which seems cool. Why is this so important? Just because I can reliably know that if Person A says they made a thing, then when I download and install that thing, I can do something to guarantee that Person A did indeed create that thing?

I'm having a hard time understanding why this makes software more inherently safe. What if Person A is malicious? Is that just up to your discretion? That doesn't seem like a great system.

How does the whole thing work from a high level? I was also reading about GPG rings of trust. Are GPG using the same keys as ssh or https? If not, what's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. Package signing enables you to verify that packages you download came from the trusted developers. This eliminates possibility for a rogue distribution server to alter in any way whatever information was signed.

But as you said - `What if Person A is malicious? Is that just up to your discretion?` - **Exactly** - signature process does not have anything to do with the intentions of the person. It will only help you to ensure that the data came from them and it was not tampered with.

Digital signature is like a passport - it proves identity of it's holder, but tells you nothing about his/her intentions.

> I'm having a hard time understanding why this makes software more inherently safe

Because it prevents unauthorized people from altering packages or source code on the distribution servers. For example, if I am hosting a public mirror of a Linux distribution on my own computer, I can replace legitimate OpenSSL package with my own malicious one. If someone will download it and run the signature verification process, it will fail, since I changed the package. A user then can decide not to install it.

For this scheme to work end users have to download public cryptographic keys from their developers and confirm that they trust them. After that they should enable signature verification process in their operating system.

Here is an [excerpt](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:X86/Working/Features#Validated_Portage_tree_snapshots) from the Gentoo documentation regarding this subject.

> How does the whole thing work from a high level? I was also reading about GPG rings of trust. Are GPG using the same keys as ssh or https? If not, what's the difference?

While I can try to explain it, I doubt I can do it better then people at https://security.stackexchange.com/ can.

Also, YouTube has [plenty](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=public%20key%20cryptography) videos on that subject.

Comment: I can't upvote your answer due to my reputation, but I can accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you know who person A is and have a reason to trust them. Thousands of other people are also trusting person A, so if they make a malicious build, there are lots of people who will catch it. Since the malicious build would be signed, they would have proof that they were betrayed by A, rather than just proof that there's some kind of problem somewhere (heck, maybe they made the malicious build themself).

By contrast, without code signing, you have to trust the entire path by which you get the code. And if you get malicious code, you have no idea who to blame or who to stop trusting.